# Julia indexing Arrays in Vector

Tags: indexing, julia

Im trying to use findnext on an array of vectors of vectors to be used for coords of other nodes connected to the indexed node in a neural net. findfirst works fine, but findnext causes a crash. I there an easy solution?

```
x  = fill!(Array(Vector{Vector{Int64}},5,5,5),[])
push!(x[1,1,1],[1,1])
push!(x[1,1,1],[1,2])
f = findfirst(x[1,1,1],[1,3])
n =  findnext(x[1,1,1],[1,3]) #Crash
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Julia `v0.3.5` and this is the error message I see:

```
julia> n =  findnext(x[1,1,1],[1,3]) #Crash
ERROR: `findnext` has no method matching findnext(::Array{Array{Int64,1},1}, ::Array{Int64,1})
```

`?findnext` reveals that it requires three arguments, `A, v, start::Integer`. The `start` is the index to *start* looking for the element:

```
julia> n =  findnext(x[1,1,1],[1,3], 1)
0
```